# nginx and htaccess rewrite rule with optional parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm trying to make a rewrite rule in `NGINX` and `.htaccess`. Now, I have a link `http://project2.local/recordings` which can be accessed like that, but it has an `optional` parameter `camera`. So you can access the link also like this: `http://project2.local/recordings/camera/1`, now it also has another option. If you go to `http://project2.local/recordings/20180118-110222` (where `20180118-110222` is a querystring), you need to "link" to another .php file, so I can run php scripts in seperated files. But I have no clue on how I should do that... I currently have this for nginx:

```
 location /camera {
         rewrite ^/camera/([^/]*)$ /camera.php?camera_id=$1 last;
 }

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /camera\.php\?camera_id=([^\&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^/?camera\.php$ /camera/%1? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^camera/([^/]*)$ /camera.php?camera_id=$1 [L]
```

Now that is for another page, but how can I do this for the page `recordings`?

It needs to have or `no parameter`, or `one parameter` (and stay on the current file) or `/camera/parameter`, which links to another .php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules with different patterns:

```
RewriteRule ^recordings/?$ recordings.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^recordings/camera/(\d+)?$ recordings.php?camera_id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^recordings/(\d+-\d+))?$ another.php?param=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```